# How to display columns as multiple values based on filter in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

For Power BI or Power Query:

I would like to create a new column which will display the columns that do not have any data in them as a multiple value cell (To contain more than 1 answer/ value). See the link as an example. The column in blue is the desired result.

Is there any formula that could be used to do this and how?

Thank you!

https://ibb.co/KDCJXws

Answer (score 0):

This should work for a pattern. Just update and duplicate the IF statements to cover all the columns you want to check so you build a temporary table with a row per column. The next step then removes the blank rows (those that do have a value) and concatenates the results.

```
VAR MyTable = 
    DATATABLE("IsEmpty", STRING,
    {
        {IF(MyTable[Column1] = BLANK(),"Column1",BLANK())},
        {IF(MyTable[Column2] = BLANK(),"Column2",BLANK())}
    }
    )
RETURN

          CONCATENATEX(FILTER(MyTable,[IsEmpty] <> BLANK() ),[IsEmpty],",")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will try it out.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not make it work. An error that I don t understand is displayed after writing the IF statement. I will try to work my way around other solutions if no new ones will be suggested here.